# How to apply custom filters to camera stream in android?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-camera

Trying to write a camera app where I can have a custom filter applied at runtime, currently sdk offer stuff such as greyscale, sephia etc and it's as simple as setting a parameter.

However I need to apply our own custom filter (where I would edit some pixels value)to both still images and videos, it shouldnt matter as the concept is the same.  I managed to do this in iOS using `opengles`, I was hoping if the same could be done on android.

The approach we tried so far is using sdk and applying a simple grey scale filter in a frame by frame basis, however the camera preview was much much slower (much lower fps) as probably it should be done at a lower level ndk or opengles.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV for Android is what you are looking for :)

http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html

If you want to further improve the performance, you can use NDK to compile your C/C++ code to make it run on the Android device. There are many samples of how to use openCv camera or Android native camera to do image/video manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is fully functional and fast on Android. You can probably reuse much of your iOS code.

Comment: any idea how to do that on android then ? (grabbing the camera stream and editing directly in it, in way that would work for both images and video) ?

Comment: It's hard to tell, only having the hint of yours that you have your work done with OpenGL on iOS. Essentially, what you do there should be portable to Android. Now, if you choose to be more specific, there is a point to discuss the requirements and the possibilities. One important difference is the pixel format: Android camera returns semi-planar YUV 420, while on iOS you can get RGB. But this is where fragment shader comes to resque.